# empty grid of UItableView using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, xcode5

I try to display objects of an array in a tableview. 
This is a single screen app, I'm using storyboard. 
When running - the tableview appears as an empty grid. the data of the objects is not displayed. what may cause this? 
Having 2 required methods *numberOfRowsInSection* and *cellForRowAtIndexPath* I suspect the last one. 
The .h file contains this row:

```
@interface MYViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

I set the delegate & datasource via the code as you suggested. still empty grid.

This is my implementation:
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { return [listRecipes.recipeArray count]; }

```
-(UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { static NSString cellIdentifier = @"ListCellIdentifier"; MYCustomListCell* listCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; NSString* dataString = listRecipes.recipeArray[indexPath.row]; listCell.listName.text = dataString; listCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:dataString]; return listCell; }
```

I try to display data from an array in MVC .
If the array is local - the data is displayed

Can you please advise what to do? 
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember to hook up your table's delegate and datasources.

Being a UIElement on a UIViewController that conforms to these two protocols is not enough for Xcode to assume that that UIViewController should be the delegate and/or datasource for the table.

Right click on your tableview, drag from delegate & datasource to your UIViewController.

You can also set these programmatically via:

```
self.table.datasource = self;
self.table.delegate = self;
```

And if you're still having trouble after this, you'll have to show us how you're implementing the datasource protocol methods.

Comment: This should be edited into the question--not pasted as comments.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your initialisation of tableview delegate and datasource would be before the **recipeArray** is initialised. In this case you will have to `tableView.reload()` after the items are added to **recipeArray** .